# Algorithm for computing rational points if the rank of Jacobian is 0

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, diophantine-equations, computer-algebra, rational-points

Is there a general algorithm that can compute in finite time all rational points on any curve of genus $g\geq 2$ whose Jacobian has rank $0$?

If not, for what special cases such algorithm is known? For genus $g=2$, we have Chabauty0 command in Magma, is it always guaranteed to work? For genus $g=3$, natural families to consider are hyperelliptic curves $y^2=P(x)$ for $P$ of degree $7$ or $8$, or Picard curves $y^3=P(x)$ for $P$ quartic. Is there an algorithm for computing rational points on them if rank if the Jacobian is $0$? Is there a corresponding Magma code?

If yes, can you provide a reference? In Cohen's book, I found the following deep theorem Demyanenko-Manin.

Let C be a curve defined over a number field K. Assume that A is a K-simple Abelian variety such that $A^m$ occurs in the decomposition of the Jacobian J of C up to isogeny over K and that
$$
m > \frac{rk(A(K))}{rk(End_K(A))},
$$
where as usual rk denotes the rank. Then C(K) is finite and can be determined explicitly.

Can we derive the result from here with, say, $K={\mathbb Q}$, $m=1$, and $A=J$? Even if yes, is there a better reference, ideally book/paper where the existence of an algorithm for the rank $0$ case is stated explicitly?

Comment: The Chabauty0 function in Magma should always work (for curves of genus 2): There is an algorithm that determines the (in this case finite) Mordell-Weil group of the Jacobian; then you take some non-constant map from the curve into its Jacobian and find the rational preimages of the known rational points on the Jacobian.

Comment: Thank you. It this open for, say, genus 3 hyperelliptic curves? If open, is this because it is difficult to determine the Mordell-Weil group of the Jacobian even in rank 0 case, or because it is difficult to find a non-constant map? Also, is Demyanenko-Manin result not covering the rank 0 case?

Comment: There is Magma code for the computation of the rational torsion subgroup of a genus 3 hyperelliptic Jacobian by Müller and Reitsma (Computing torsion subgroups of Jacobians of hyperelliptic curves of genus 3, Res. Number Theory 9 (2023), no.2, Paper No. 23, 26 pp.). One could use this to write a function like Chabauty0 for genus 3 hyperelliptic curves.

Comment: I think applying Demyanenko-Manin in the rank zero case comes down to finding a bound for the height of the points on the curve. (Torsion points on the Jacobian have canonical height zero, so bounded naive height, which results in a height bound for the rational points on the curve). The problem is to make this bound explicit. There may be geneal results in this direction in the literature somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an algorithm due to Bjorn Poonen (Computing torsion points on curves, Experiment. Math. 10 (2001), no.3, 449–465) that, given a (not necessarily rational) base-point $P_0$ on the curve, finds all (geometric) points $P$ on the curve such that $[P-P_0]$ is torsion in the Jacobian. This solves an even harder problem! (Although, as far as I know, this has been implemented only for curves of genus 2 with a Weierstraß point as base-point.)

Comment: Thank you. In your other answer, you gave a method for which you cannot prove that it will always work. However, in this answer you (and the abstract of the paper) are talking about ALGORITHM for a more general problem, hence for this problem, right? So, can I write "Theorem. There is an algorithm for computing all rational points on any curve of genus $g\geq 2$ and rank of the Jacobian 0", and refer to this paper for a proof?

Comment: I would think so, yes. (Whether this is satisfying depends on whether you want a theoretical result or a practical algorithm.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sketch of a method that could be able to do what you want. (I won't call it an *algorithm*, since I cannot prove that it will always work.) I will write $X$ for the curve and $J$ for its Jacobian.

1. For a number of odd primes $p$ of good reduction for $X$, determine $J(\mathbb F_p)$ (Magma can do this). Let $e$ be the gcd of the exponents of all these (finite abelian) groups.
2. Pick a base point $P_0 \in X(\mathbb Q)$ (or show that no rational point exists, in which case we are done).
3. For odd primes $q$ of good reduction for $X$, find the subset $S_q$ of $X(\mathbb F_q)$ consisting of points $\bar{P}$ such that $e \cdot [\bar{P} - \bar{P}_0] = 0$ in $J(\mathbb F_q)$. For each $\bar{P} \in S_q$, try to find a point $P \in X(\mathbb Q)$ reducing mod $q$ to it. If this can be done for each $\bar{P}$, the resulting set of points is $X(\mathbb Q)$.
   Otherwise, try the next prime $q$.

If this method terminates, it gives the correct answer (the reason for this is that the reduction maps $J(\mathbb Q) \to J(\mathbb F_p)$ and
$X(\mathbb Q) \to X(\mathbb F_q)$ are injective). But I have no good intuition at this point how likely it is to be successful.